# OpenRasta resource registration with codecs for three different MIME types and extensions

Tags: c#, .net, url, mime-types, openrasta

In OpenRasta, how am I supposed to register resources with three different codecs and access these codecs through a regular web browser by appending an extension to the URL? The following doesn't seem to work:

```
MediaType json = MediaType.Json.WithQuality(1f);
MediaType xml = MediaType.Xml.WithQuality(0.9f);
MediaType html = MediaType.Html.WithQuality(0.1f);

ResourceSpace.Has
    .ResourcesOfType<ResourceBase>()
    .WithoutUri
    .TranscodedBy<MyXmlCodec>().ForMediaType(xml).ForExtension("xml")
    .And.TranscodedBy<MyHtmlCodec>().ForMediaType(html).ForExtension("html")
    .And.TranscodedBy<JsonDataContractCodec>().ForMediaType(json).ForExtension("json");

ResourceSpace.Has
    // UserListResource inherits ResourceBase
    .ResourcesOfType<UserListResource>()
    .AtUri("/users")
    .HandledBy<UserHandler>();
```

`UserListResource` is registered and made available as `text/html` in a regular web browser, but appending `.xml` to the URL just gives me a 404. I've tried this:

```
ResourceSpace.Has
    // UserListResource inherits ResourceBase
    .ResourcesOfType<UserListResource>()
    .AtUri("/users")
    .And.AtUri("/users.xml")
    .HandledBy<UserHandler>();
```

But that only gives me the same `text/html` representation on both `/users` and  `/users.xml`.

Comment: See my other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4960008/59816

Comment: @ScottLittlewood, I can't get the `ContentTypeExtensionUriDecorator` to work. Adding it doesn't really make any difference to my app; requesting any URI with `.xml` suffixed just results in a 404. Ideas?